# Filter Linux logs based on Unix Timestamp

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log on a linux server. The entries are in the format:

[timestamp (seconds since jan 1 1970)] log data entry

I need a bash script that will take the name of the log file and output only yesterdays entries (from 12:00 to 23:59:59 of previous day) and output those lines to a new file.

I've seen various scripts that filter logs based on dates but all of them so far deal with date stamps in more human readable formats, or are not dynamic. They rely on hard coded dates. I want a script that is going to run in a cron job daily so it has to be aware of what the current date is each time it runs.

Thanks.

**Update**: This is what I have so far. It just never seems to do the evaluation of the date. It prints 00 for the date so everything gets through.

```
head -5 logfile.log | awk '{
    if($1 >= (date -d "today 00:00:00" +"%s")) 
        print $1 (date -d "today 00:00:00" +"%s");
    }'
```

I'm confused though, even if the date evaluates properly, $1 is going to have numbers inside square brackets, and my date will be just numbers. Will it do the comparison properly if the strings are formatted differently like that? I haven't figured out how to shove the date number returned by date into a string with brackets yet.

Comment: You'll be interested in `date -d "yesterday 00:00:00"` and `date -d "yesterday 23:59:59"`

Comment: I recommend @glennjackman's answer, combined with [awk conditionals](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/)

Comment: I recommend to add date's option `+"%s"`.

Comment: I've updated my question with a stab at the answer, but I think you guys are underestimating the level of my noobness at this Linux scripting stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe using the dates as Dale said. But using a little trick to extract the "[" and "]", and after compare the dates. Something like this:

```
YESTERDAY=$(date -d "yesterday 00:00:00" +"%s")
TODAY=$(date -d "today 00:00:00" +"%s")

# Combine the processing in awk
awk -v MIN=${YESTERDAY} -v MAX=${TODAY} -F["]""["] '{  if ( $2 >=  MIN && $2 <= MAX) print $0}' logfile.log
```

Comment: In the end I negotiated to avoid filtering logs and just use the backups created by logrotate on a weekly basis instead, but I tested this answer and it seems to work. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
YESTERDAY=$(date -d "yesterday 00:00:00" +"%s")  
TODAY=$(date -d "today 00:00:00" +"%s")

cat your_log.log | \  
awk -v MIN=${YESTERDAY} -v MAX=${TODAY} \
'{if($1 >= MIN && $1 < MAX) print}'
```

:)
Dale

Answer (score 0):

Combining tips and tricks from Glenn, Dale, and Davison:

`awk -v today=$(date -d "today 00:00:00" +"%s") -v yesterday=$(date -d "yesterday 00:00:00" +"%s") -F'[\\[\\] ]' '{ if($2 >= yesterday && $2 < today) print }' logfile.log`

Uses the shell's `$()` command substitution to feed variables to awk's `-v` argument parser
`-F'[\\[\\] ]'` sets the field separator to be either `[`, `]`, or

input data:

```
[1300000000 log1 data1 entry1]
[1444370000 log2 data2 entry2]
[1444374000 log3 data3 entry3]
[1444460399 log4 data4 entry4]
[1500000000 log5 data5 entry5]
```

output:

```
[1444370000 log2 data2 entry2]
```