# How to check last 10-hours change in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, file, logging, sed, grep

I'm trying to check last 10 hours change in /var/log/messages with following commands (grep and sed). Grep is pulling all the data from last 3 days. Sed is running successfully but no result.
Can someone please help me out with these commands or any other commands to check changes in log files.

```
sed -n "/^$(date '+%b %_d %H:%M' -d -10 hours)/,\$p" /var/log/messages

grep "^$(date +'%Y-%M-%d %H %M' -d -10 hours)" /var/log/messages
```

Comment: `date: extra operand ‘hours’` - when running your `date` command

Comment: learn to search first for an answer, i.e. `[linux] filter log file by date` returns 13 Q/A. The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000824/filter-linux-logs-based-on-unix-timestamp is perfectly usable for this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Linux logs based on Unix Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000824/filter-linux-logs-based-on-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the following command

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-600 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")" \
    -v d2="$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || 
    $0 ~ d2' /var/log/messages
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're on a SystemD-based Linux, you can use `journalctl`
instead of direct file access of `/var/log/messages`.

`journalctl` supports a `--since/-S` option which accepts a timestamp
formatted according to `systemd.time(7)` (man page).  So for your case
you can simply use `-10h` as "ten hours ago":

```
journalctl -S-10h
```

Comment: I knew this must have been a solved problem, I just didn't know what had solved it. Perfect.